# while true in Coroutine LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using coroutine livedata to do some stuff every 4 seconds. This is the code I used

```
val reloadInterval: MutableLiveData<Long> = MutableLiveData()
val data = reloadInterval.switchMap { delay ->
    liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while (true) {
            delay(delay)
            emit(data)
        }
    }
}

fun reloadInterval(interval: Long) {
    reloadInterval.value = interval
}
```

So my question is when I change the reloadInterval value the switchMap flow get triggered and return a new livedata then will the old livedata still running or it will stopped automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `liveData {` coroutine builder's `block` is only executed while the LiveData is active. The block runner is cancelled after a given timeout period, which is by default 5 seconds.

So `while(true) {` will stop after 5 seconds. You can pass `liveData(timeoutInMs = 0) {` to immediately terminate the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't keep a subscription to the old livedata, it should should become inactive. See [LiveData.onInactive()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#oninactive) for more information